# Best way of message passing from GameLoop (Main loop) on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Does excessive message passing (function calling) from a game Loop which is scheduled at 60 Hz make game performance worse? In my gameLoop a lot of work needs to be performed. So which is the better way: writing everything in GameLoop function or splitting the work into several function and then calling them from gameLoop?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think the best advice is to go for the clearest implementation, i.e., separating your code.  If you have performance issues, then profile to find the culprits - which will be much easier if your code is clear and then optimise.

Comment: This is so true. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Ok, but my main concern is performance. If i divide the code & passing a lot of message in short time is there is any chance of performance degradation? Whats about overhead of message passing in objective C?? is it become too costly for a number(8-10) message passing in quick interval??

Comment: I don't know the answer to that but I am sure one of the gurus will chip in.  In my own experience the biggest culprit when optimising is object creation not message passing and with highly graphical stuff it is the rendering that takes the time not generally the code inbetween.  So things like flattening the view heirarchy and using opaque images where your can will all help, but until you profile you won't know.  HTH Dave

Comment: Ok,Thanks for your answer. I am going to split the game loop.

Comment: No problem, and do let us know how you get on and if I can help.  Dave.